# How do I take a string and keep only the parts of the string before the space?

Tags: c, string, whitespace

More specifically, I need to check if a user input for a name is only the first name and if not, keep only the first name (so cut out everything succeeding a space). How do I check for a space within a string and keep only the parts before the space?

Comment: [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)?

Comment: You can iterate through each char in a string and use strcmp() to check if you encountered a space. extract only the first index until the index of the space found.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion - use [strcspn](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strspn)

```
#include <string.h>
...
size_t nbytes = strcspn (s, " ");
if (nbytes > 0)
  s[nbytes] = '\0';
```